# Endless Scrolling Slideshow Animation

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an endless scrolling slideshow purely in CSS.

The only problem I'm having is how to get the first element to slide back in from the right once the animation has finished 1 stage of its loop... instead of just suddenly appearing because the animation is restarting.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

*{margin:0 auto;overflow:hidden;}


.pic {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

#one{
background:rgba(23,230,120,0.9);
animation: scroll1 4s infinite;
}

#two{
background:rgba(230,23,180,0.9);
right:-100%;
animation: scroll 4s infinite;
}

#three{
background:rgba(23,230,220,0.9);
right:-200%;
animation: scroll 4s infinite;
}

#four{
background:rgba(230,80,220,0.9);
right:-300%;
animation: scroll 4s infinite;
}

#contain{
position:absolute;
width:400%;
height:100%;
left:0;
}

@keyframes scroll
{
from {left:0;}
20% {left:0;}
25% {left:-100%;}
45% {left:-100%;}
50% {left:-200%;}
70% {left:-200%;}
75% {left:-300%;}
to {left:-300%;}
}

@keyframes scroll1
{
from {left:0;}
20% {left:0;}
25% {left:-100%;opacity:1;}
45% {left:-100%;opacity:0;}
50% {left:100%;opacity:0;}
to {left:100%;opacity:1;}
}



</style>
<body>

<div id="contain" class="pic">
<div id="one" class="pic"></div>
<div id="two" class="pic"></div>
<div id="three" class="pic"></div>
<div id="four" class="pic"></div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a JSFiddle ou Codepen example (or something similar) to help us helping you. :)

Comment: @gnclmorais copy the code in an html file and execute in your browser.

Comment: @R3tep. I agree with gnclmorais, provide a jsfiddle so it is easier for people to help. I wont even bother helping if a poster can not be bothered making it easy for us.  Also, I will be very surprised if you can get an endless slideshow working without js. I've never seen one

Comment: @R3tep [link](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/#4) I just found this, it looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

After a couple hours messing around with div sizes and timing I found the solution! There wasn't a lot of information, but I used [this site](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/#2)'s ideas: 
and simplified them a bit.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
</script>
<style>

*{margin:0 auto;overflow:hidden;}

body{
background:black;
}

.pic {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
animation: scroll 10s infinite;
}

#one{
background:rgba(23,230,120,0.9);
animation: scroll1 10s infinite;
}

#two{
background:rgba(230,23,180,0.9);
right:-200%;
}

#three{
background:rgba(23,230,220,0.9);
right:-400%;
}

#four{
background:rgba(230,80,220,0.9);
right:-600%;
}

#contain{
position:absolute;
/*top:100px;*/
width:100%;
height:100%;
left:0;
}














@keyframes scroll
{
from {left:0;}
20% {left:0;}
25% {left:-200%;}
45% {left:-200%;}
50% {left:-400%;}
70% {left:-400%;}
75% {left:-600%;}
95% {left:-600%;}
to {left:-800%;}
}

@keyframes scroll1 {
0%   {left:0;}
20%  {left:0; z-index:1;}
25%  {left:-100%; z-index:0; opacity:1;}
26%  {left:-100%; z-index:-1; opacity:0;}
27%  {left:100%; z-index:-1;}
70%  {left:100%; z-index:10;opacity:1;}
95%  {left:100%;}
100% {left:0;}
}




</style>
<body>

<div id="contain">
<div id="one" class="pic"></div>
<div id="two" class="pic"></div>
<div id="three" class="pic"></div>
<div id="four" class="pic"></div>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

I urge you to try this code for yourself!